# WebGL optimization for single page websites

Tags: three.js, webgl, single-page-application

We have a single page website that uses Barba.js for Ajax loaded page transitions. We have WebGL background animations on several of the pages, and it runs well when you only have one animation loaded at a time. The problem we are having is that since this is a single-page website, when you navigate away from a page, the WebGL animation from the previous page is still running. This causes the memory usage to increase every time you navigate to a new page with WebGL content.

What is the best way to handle this? I've spent this entire week doing research, so I'm aware that WebGL contexts are garbage collected only. Everyone keeps saying to save the context for displaying later, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid because it uses a ton of memory and slows the whole site down if I try to just hold all the WebGL contexts.

I've tried every dirty method I could find to try to find and delete all references to a context before loading the next page. After 3 days of trying, I managed to cut down on memory usage a little bit but not super effectively. I wanted to find a better solution.

At this point I'm looking for suggestions on how I can refactor all the WebGL code into one coherent structure so each animation can be turned on and off whenever I need them, so that only one animation is using memory at a time. Is that possible?

Comment: If you're using three.js, are you calling `.dispose()` on geometry, textures, and materials after you're done using them?

Comment: If all else fails put the webgl animations in a frame. Set each one on its own html page. Replace the content of the frame when you want to hide or change the animation in your one page app? Then you can load anything you want without much to do, Video, 3d, images...

Comment: @Radio I do like that iframe idea, I will try that.

Comment: @Radio Alright sir, a million thanks to you. That worked perfectly! Please put that in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @chrispytoes thank you. However it doesn't explicitly answer the question, merely a simpler architecture. Memory management in Javascript's auto gc environment is a technical challenge. It seems overwrought to attempt to address this challenge in a one page production app that may be overdue on a deadline or expectation. While the use of an iframe allows for a method to dump ram in this case, it's all or nothing. It solves the use case but not the underlying challenge when an i frame is not feasible. Better to let the question stand and see what people have for solutions, if anything. Cheers!